# PHP error class '..' not found

Tags: php

I'm getting the following error:

> Fatal error: Class 'ViewController' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\blogando\view\site\index.php on line 3

The structure of my project (which is MVC):

[image]

The error file:

[image]

Comment: that's an image of a file, we don't know what is inside, but the error is self explainatory :S

Comment: I assume you missed a '/' in your path

Comment: If you have no autoloader then you must explicitly include that class definition before you try to use it.  If you do have an autoloader, then it's not working or `ViewController` is in a different namespace.

Comment: Why can't you copy the test of the PHP and paste it?!?!?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Index.php should be in the web root for your site.